# По последовательному порту принимаються не те данные

Tags: c#, .net, serial

Пишу програму для управления устройством по последовательному порту. Каждая команда это масив бит и должна начинаться на `FC`.
Пример команд:

```
Status Request --->
[FC 05 11 27 56]
             <--- Idling
                [FC 05 11 27 56]
Status Request --->
[FC 05 11 27 56]
             <--- ACCEPTING
                [FC 05 12 BC 64]
Status Request --->
[FC 05 11 27 56]
             <--- Reject 77
                [FC 06 17 77 67 E9]
```

---

Мне почемуто в ответете место `FC` приходит `3F` из за чего не могу посчитать CRC нормально. Я конечно мог `3F` менять на `FC` в ручную, но не думаю что это правильное решение.

```
 public void CommOpen(string port, int bauld)
    {
        try
        {
            _serialPort = new SerialPort(port, bauld, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);
            _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
            _serialPort.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }


  private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(_serialPort.ReadExisting());
        if (ba.Length >= 5)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("<------------");
                var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
                Console.WriteLine(hexString);
                if (CheckCRC(ba))
                {
                    switch (ba[2])
                    {
                        case ENABLE:
                            Console.WriteLine("Inhibit");
                            break;
                        case INITIALIZE:
                            Console.WriteLine("Initializing");
                            break;
                        case ACCEPTING:
                            Console.WriteLine("accepting");
                            break;
                        case ESCROW:
                            Console.WriteLine("ESCROW");
                            break;
                        case STACKING:
                            Console.WriteLine("STACKING");
                            break;
                        case VENDVALID:
                            Console.WriteLine("vendvalid");
                            break;
                        case STACKED:
                            Console.WriteLine("stacked");
                            break;
                        case REJECTING:
                            Console.WriteLine("rejecting");
                            break;
                        case RETURNING:
                            Console.WriteLine("returning");
                            break;
                        case HOLDING:
                            Console.WriteLine("holding");
                            break;
                        case DISABLE:
                            Console.WriteLine("disable");
                            break;
                        case INVALID_COMMAND:
                            Console.WriteLine("INVALID_COMMAND");
                            break;
                        case POWERUP:
                            Console.WriteLine("Powerup");
                            break;
                        case COMUNICATION_ERROR:
                            Console.WriteLine("COMUNICATION_ERROR");
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("command error");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: `FC` и `3F` в бинарном представлении отличаются на два нуля. По какой-то причине эти два нуля у вас теряются. Попробуйте снизить частоту передачи данных и другие значения `StopBits`. Возможно, проблема не в C# коде, а в вашем устройстве.

Comment: @Astronavigator согласен насчет параметров передачи. Для диагностики нужно использовать заведомо рабочую терминалку.

Comment: @Astronavigator @Владимир Мартьянов  Вроде все как в документации. [скрин](http://imgur.com/a/N6QCc) Когда вручную заменяю на `FC`  CRC номально считаеться.

Comment: Попробуйте увеличить паузы, может быть, устройство не справляется с вашей скоростью.

Comment: @VladD Использую 9600 бод

Comment: Хм. Может, другие параметры соединения неправильные?